# .htaccess rewriterule for changing the url

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)$ index.php?page=games&game=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I need for this to work:

*index.php?page=music should be url.com/music*

*index.php?page=games should be url.com/games*

*index.php?page=games&game=example should be url.com/games/example*

Please help me write my .htaccess for this

Comment: And what is the problem with your current rules? Don't they work? What do or don't they do?

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    rewriterule ^index.php?page=music(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/music$1 [r=301,nc]
rewriterule ^index.php?page=music(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/music$1 [r=301,nc]
rewriterule ^index.php?page=games(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/games$1 [r=301,nc]
rewriterule ^index.php?page=games&game=example(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/games/example$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: The OP wants to rewrite the url, not redirect them.